# Pass specific table ID value to AJAX request from Modal

Tags: c#, jquery, html, .net

I have an AJAX request that I am making to move a catalog from one group to another. Essentially, all this does is update one row in a table. My problem is that I don't send the request from a modal, and at that point I'm not sure how to know which row in the table (which catalog ID) to send with the request. What's causing me issues is that my modal is outside of my `foreach` loop where I run through displaying each catalog.

I've tried a few different things, like attaching the Catalog ID to the modal's data, then grabbing it once the modal shows (which is what I've tried below), but my parameter still comes through null. I have a backend controller method and have no issues there, I am just struggling with how to pass the proper Catalog ID to the call. Here's some code:

Modal:

```
<div id="frmMoveCatalog" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="frmMoveCatalog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center" id="frmCatalogLabel">Move Catalog to Group</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="container-fluid form-group">
                                <label for="txtGroupName" class="control-label">Current Group: @Model.Group.Name</label>
                                <br />
                                <label for="txtGroupCode" class="control-label">Select new group:</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("txtGroupID",
                                    lGroupCodes,
                                    "Select Group",
                                    new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-fluid form-group">
                                <input class="btn btn-primary text-right pull-right btn-move-catalog" type="button" value="Move" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

HTML/C# .NET Table:

```
@foreach (var lCatalogVersion in Model.LatestCatalogVersions)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="fa-chevron-down"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    @if (!lCatalogVersion.IsPublished)
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="#">Activate Version</a></li>
                                    }
                                    <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                                    @if (lCatalogVersion.IsPublished)
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="@Url.Content($"~/Catalog/{lCatalogVersion.Guid}/Copy")">Copy to New Version</a></li>
                                    }
                                    <li><a class="fa-folder pointer" data-target="#frmMoveCatalog" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="move this catalog to a new group" data-catalogid="@lCatalogVersion.CatalogID">Move Catalog to New Group</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="@Url.Content($"~/Catalog/{lCatalogVersion.Guid}")">@lCatalogVersion.Code</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @lCatalogVersion.Guid.ToString()
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="@Url.Content($"~/Catalog/{lCatalogVersion.Guid}")">@lCatalogVersion.GetName(Steelcase.Application.EBusiness.CatalogBuilder.DataModel.MetaData.LanguageEnum.English)</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @lCatalogVersion.GetDescription(Steelcase.Application.EBusiness.CatalogBuilder.DataModel.MetaData.LanguageEnum.English)
                        </td>
                        <td data-sort="@lCatalogVersion.VersionNumber.SortableVersionNumber()">
                            @if (lCatalogVersion.Status == CatalogVersion.CatalogVersionStatusEnum.Active)
                            {
                                <a href="@Url.Content($"~/Catalog/{lCatalogVersion.Guid}/Version")">@lCatalogVersion.VersionNumber.ToString()</a>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var lVersion = Model.ActiveCatalogVersions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == lCatalogVersion.Code);
                                if (lVersion != null)
                                {
                                    <a href="@Url.Content($"~/Catalog/{lVersion.Guid}/Version")">@lVersion.VersionNumber.ToString()</a>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <text>N/A</text>
                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td data-sort="@lCatalogVersion.VersionNumber.SortableVersionNumber()">
                            <a href="@Url.Content($"~/Catalog/{lCatalogVersion.Guid}/Version")">@lCatalogVersion.VersionNumber.ToString()</a> (@lCatalogVersion.Status.ToString())
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (lAllCatalogTags.ContainsKey(lCatalogVersion.ID))
                            {
                                foreach (TagValue lTag in lAllCatalogTags[lCatalogVersion.ID])
                                {
                                    <span class="label label-default">@lTag.Value</span>
                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

AJAX Code/Call:

```
$(function () {
        var $container = $('#div-@lGuid');
        var moveGroupModal = $container.find('#frmMoveCatalog');
        moveGroupModal.on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var pCatalogID = $(event.relatedTarget).data('val');
            moveGroupModal.data('pCatalogID', pCatalogID);
        });

        var btnMoveCatalog = $container.find('.btn-move-catalog');
            btnMoveCatalog.click(function () {
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append("pGroupID", $container.find('#txtGroupID').val());
            form.append("pCatalogID", $('#moveGroupModal').data('pCatalogID'));

            $.post({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Group/" + Model.Group.Guid + "/MoveCatalog")',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form,
                success: function (data) {
                        if (data.error) {
                            //Show error
                            scs.site.alert('Error', data.message);
                        } else {
                        $('#frmMoveCatalog').modal('hide');
                        $("#catalog-list").html(data);
                        }
                    },
                error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) { scs.site.alert('Error', textStatus + ':' + errorThrown); },
                cache: false
            });
        });
    });
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the following:

```
moveGroupModal.on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            pCatalogID = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-catalogid');
        });
```

I then use `pCatalogID` in the AJAX call as my variable to pass to the form. The `$(event.relatedtarget)` returns which element entered or exited the modal.